# JavaScript JSON output into a <textarea> or a <div>

Tags: javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    url: baseDir + 'somepage.php?ajax=true&rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType : "script",
    data: 'somedata=' + JSON.stringify(something),
    success: function(jsonData)
    {
        //do something
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        //error
    }
});
```

I have this code which works ok, the response from page somepage.php is this:

```
somefunction(55, new Array('1', '2', '3'), 0, 0, 0);
$('#someid').val('123');
```

Which is evaluated as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.

My question is: how do I put the output into a debug `<textarea id="something"><textarea>` ... or a div, to view the output for debugging?

Comment: That's not JSON output, it's Javascript.

Comment: Thank you, anyone got my point, sorry for my mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery.text();

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
    $('#myDiv').text(textStatus)
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you! Take a look at [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```
success: function(jsonData)
{
    $("textarea#something").val(jsonData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    success: function(jsonData)
    {
        $("#DIVname").text(jsonData);
    }
```

This worked for me to display the output in a `<div>`.

Thank you both!